# Reactjs - Make the get request when loading the page

Tags: reactjs

I know that in Angular there is ngOnInit. In Reactjs is there something similar to do the get request when loading the page?

I have a table and I need to get the request when I load the page for me to display the data in the table.

```
export default function ListAdverts() {

    const columns = [
        {
            label: "Título",
            accessor: "title",
            width: "194px"
        },
        {
            label: "Valor",
            accessor: "price_cents",
            width: "131px"
        },
        {
            label: "Anunciante",
            accessor: "title",
            width: "203px"
        },
        {
            label: "Categoria",
            accessor: "title",
            width: "158px"
        }
    ];

    const [dataAdverts, setdDataAdverts] = React.useState([]);

    return (
        <Table
            rows={dataAdverts}
            columns={columns}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data fetching for components is usually done inside the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook

```
export default function ListAdverts() {
    const columns = ...

    const [dataAdverts, setdDataAdverts] = React.useState([]);

    // fetch data here
    // runs only once because of empty dependency array
    React.useEffect(() => { 
      let isCancelled = false

       const fetchSomeData = async () => {
          const data = await someApiRequest()

          // only update state if component isn't unmounted
          // if you try to update state on an unmounted component,
          // React will throw an error
          if (!isCancelled) {
             setdDataAdverts(data)
          }
       }
       fetchSomeData()

       // cleanup
       return () => {
         isCancelled = true
       }
    }, [])

    return (
        <Table
            rows={dataAdverts}
            columns={columns}
        />
    )
}
```